# Partial access to class attributes

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, attributes

Consider 3 classes:

Data

Manipulator1

Manipulator2

Data class has some attributes: a,b,c

I'm looking for a design pattern so the *Manipulator1* only has r/w access to **a** and **b** while *Manipulator2* can change just **b** and **c**.

Any ideas?

I'm coding in Java BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be seen as an application case of the [Proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) with the proxy regulating access to the Data object.

Personally, I consider it enough to program the manipulators to access the relevant fields only, but if access restriction on the data is a must for fear of malicious clients or similar, then proxy is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could let the Data class implement two different interfaces and let the Manipulator classes each know only one of them.

You also might want to have a look at the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).